# HTML Tags Don't Work When Text Resized

Tags: html, flash, actionscript, resize, textfield

I have a text field that gets populated dynamically. If the populated text doesn't fit in the text field, the text gets resized. HTML tags work correctly in the dynamically populated text, but only if the text doesn't get resized. *HTML tags are completed ignored in resized text.* Any ideas?

**Code for the text field:**

```
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.Font;
    //
    function setDesc(str:String):void{
      var fmtD:TextFormat;
      var cfmtD:TextFormat = this.desc_txt.getTextFormat()==null ? this.desc_text.defaultTextFormat : this.desc_txt.getTextFormat();
      var sizeD:int = 22;
      desc_txt.htmlText = str;
      while(sizeD>10 && sizeD<23 && desc_txt.textHeight>255){
         sizeD--;
         fmtD = new TextFormat(descFont.fontName,sizeD,0x000000,false, false,false);
         desc_txt.htmlText = str;
         desc_txt.setTextFormat(fmtD);
      } 
}
```

**Code to populate the text field:**

```
    function openDialog(e:MouseEvent){
    dialog_window.doOpen();
      switch(e.currentTarget.name){
         case "btn_structure":
            dialog_window.setTitle("Business Structure:");
            dialog_window.setDesc("This topic discusses the <b>basic</b> structure of the business area.");
         break;
         case "btn_services":
            dialog_window.setTitle("Services Provided:");
            dialog_window.setDesc("This topic provides <i>information</i> about the services offered by the Client Billing Services unit.");
         break;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the **last two lines** inside the **while loop** to:

```
desc_txt.defaultTextFormat = fmtD;
desc_txt.htmlText = str;
```

You can read more about [working with html tags and the as3 TextFormat class here](http://www.thumbleaf.com/journal/?p=210)

EDIT:

I just set up this simple example using bits of your code and both the text formatting (font type and size) and html tags (bold and italics) are working flawlessly:

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

var sizeD:uint = 22;
var desc_txt:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(desc_txt);

var str:String = "This topic <i>discusses</i> the <b>basic</b> structure of the business area. This topic <i>discusses</i> the <b>basic</b> structure of the business area.This topic <i>discusses</i> the <b>basic</b> structure of the business area. This topic <i>discusses</i> the <b>basic</b> structure of the business area.";

var fmtD:TextFormat;
fmtD = new TextFormat("Verdana",sizeD,0x000000,false, false,false);

desc_txt.width=450;
desc_txt.height=150;
desc_txt.wordWrap=true;

desc_txt.defaultTextFormat = fmtD;
desc_txt.htmlText = str;

var maxHeight = 150;

trace(sizeD+" - "+ desc_txt.textHeight);
while(sizeD>10 && sizeD<23 && desc_txt.textHeight>maxHeight)
{
  trace("--> inside while loop");
  sizeD--;
  fmtD = new TextFormat("Verdana",sizeD,0x000000,false, false,false);
  desc_txt.defaultTextFormat = fmtD;
  desc_txt.htmlText = str;

}
trace(sizeD+" - "+desc_txt.textHeight);
```

Comment: 255 is the height of the text box.

Comment: 255 is the height of the text box. My problem is that there could be too much text to fit into the text box, therefore it gets resized.  When that happens, the HTML tags don't work.

In your example, the text doesn't wrap, so when you add more content to the string it cuts off.  My text box is 455.40W by 255H.

Comment: My bad, I was mistaken about TextField.textHeight. Anyways, I fixed up my simple code example using wordwrap and it's working great both when it resizes and when it doesn't need to. Please make sure to use desc_txt.defaultTextFormat = fmtD; instead of setTextFormat(fmtD); everytime.

Comment: Thank you!  It took a few tries, but I finally was able to work your code into mine.